# Green Highlighted Text in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I created a word document at home, and edited some of it at school, then at school saved the document to my OneDrive.

Now that I have got home from school and loaded up the document from my OneDrive, it shows all of the work I added at school. But has highlighted any new stuff in green, and I can't find a way of removing the green highlight.

To be clear the Microsoft Account that I signed into to access the document was my personal one, but Word was signed into my school Microsoft Account.

So how do I turn this feature off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have `Tracked Changes`, `Comments` or `Collaboration` turned on. If one of those is turned on, it will mark changes and comments with different colors.

Answer (score 0):

When you print or save it as pdf some of the text turns green, I don't know the exact reason but  I know how to solve it.
select the text in green
hover or go to styles in home
press clear formatting
This is time taking but works

Answer (score -1):

This is due to highlighting changes in the document from different locations, useful for pruning through any additions made by collaborators.

Can be turned off by going to the review pane, clicking on "show markup" in the track changes section and uncheck "highlight updates."